# Getting Total Votes Form mysql table and Compare it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with

```
id primary key,     nominee_id,     cat_id,     user_id(voter id),  vote_status,    date
```

these fields, We have nominees for this voting process under different categories, so each nominees can be nimnated to more than one category. ok, all process is going well, I can take total count of votes got for each nominees in each category. but I dont have any idea How to get the winner from this table using SQL. 
I want to get Most votes gained Nominees in each category, however as I said I can get total votes got for each nominees in each category using

`SELECT nominee_id FROM voting WHERE`cat_id`= $cid`.

Is it possible get this through another SQL statement, or else can anyone suggest any other way to get this.

below is the table, I want to get back the Nominee_id who got max Vote in a particulat cat_id, eg: in hte below table I want to get nominee_id 29 as a winner in cat_id 3, because he got two votes in that category

[image]

Comment: Show some sample data & expected data!!

Comment: Why don't you try using `order by counted desc` and `group by category ` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the winner from each category.

`SELECT nid, cid, max(votes) as final_votes from (select nominee_id as nid, cat_id as cid, count(user_id) as votes from voting group by cat_id, nominee_id) nv GROUP BY cid order by  final_votes desc;`

---

Comment: Thank you for your response, please see the updated question, I am not a SQL geek

Comment: Try out the query on the your data set. It should work. The query does exactly what you want

Comment: I am usually not for spoon feeding, but you can try it this way: $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT nid, cid, max(votes) as final_votes from (select nominee_id as nid, cat_id as cid, count(user_id) as votes from ".$wpdb->prefix."voting group by cat_id, nominee_id) nv GROUP BY cid order by  final_votes desc"));

Answer (score 0):

This one should work

```
SELECT nominee_id, COUNT(nominee_id) AS countNominee FROM voting WHERE 
vote_status = 'yes' GROUP BY cat_id ORDER BY countNominee DESC
```

Comment: thanks for response, your query returns me this array ::  Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [nominee_id] => 29 [nominatedTimes] => 3 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [nominee_id] => 74 [nominatedTimes] => 1 ) ), seems ok, but I am not expecting this array, eg; in this case I need only nominee_id => 29 as a result(array), can i get that please

Comment: oops, that returns all nominees in that category, your previous query was ok, but that was showing same result for all categories, If that fixed by using a simple LIMI 1 would have fixed the issues.